# LightSwitch v2 - Unable to load data

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have seen many posts to this problem but no prescribed solution worked for me, so I am trying again.

*Problem summary*:
LightSwitch application (in-browser 3-tier) using Visual Studio 2012 - Users from remote machines are able to authenticate ok (Windows Auth) but actual business data is not displayed (I get "red Xs" showing "Unable to load data...").

**UPDATE: The issue is when running it with other browser other then IE. In IE it all works ok!**

On the web server, if I go to "Browse *:80" in IIS7 everything works ok:
[image]

But if I run from a client machine across the Internet (no VPN, different domain) I get the error (I am using Google Chrome):
[image]

Interestly, using Fiddler I can see that the data IS actually coming in:
[image]

Server info:

- Windows 2008 R2 with .Net 4.5 as well as the LightSwitch 2011 pre-requisites  installed through WPI.
- SQL Server 2008 Std on the same server

LightSwitch App Settings:

- Use Windows Auth (Allow any uthenticated Windows user)
- Application type: Web
- Application Server Config: IIS

IIS Settings:

- App Pool: .Net=4.0.30319, Managed pipeline mode=Integrated
- Connection Strings: only 1 VALID connection string using SQL Server authentication (SQL Server user is SysAdmin)
- .Net Authorization Rules: Allow - All Users

I am sure I am missing something simple, could you please help me figure this out?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is it fetching data using Ajax? Could it be that the problem is related to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) handling? If so have a look at [this](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/ajax-cross-domain-142169) and [this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/). Also Google for "cross origin resource sharing".

Comment: It is not ajax; it's silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug. You mustn't have seen this workaround? I can't tell you if it works, as I haven't started using VS/LS 2012 yet, but I hope it'll help you.

[Working Around The Chrome Data Loading Bug in VS 2012 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattev/archive/2012/06/25/working-around-the-chrome-data-loading-bug-in-lightswitch-2012-rc.aspx)

If you're still using the RC, instead of the RTM version (& I'd assume that this would be fixed in the final version, seeing as the workaround comes from an LS team member), maybe the workaround will fix the problem for you.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously missed that one, probably because I was not searching at all by "chome". Thanks for the work around!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - in the client machine I was running Chrome. As soon as I tried with IE it worked!!!

I can't believe I spent so much time on this. :(